# Show that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_{k}|}} = 1$, a conclusion cannot be made on whether $\sum^{\infty}_{n}|a_{n}|$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_{k} \neq 0$, $\forall\ k\in{\mathbb{N}}$. Show that if $\lim_{k\to\infty}{\frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_{k}|}} = 1$, then a conclusion cannot be made on whether $\sum^{\infty}_{1}|a_{k}|$ is convergent.

---

I understand why this is true, for example if $a_{k} = \frac{1}{k}$, but I am having trouble putting this into a formal proof. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}=1$$ but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. This example shows that we cannot conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges knowing $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$.

If $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2}=1$$ and
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. This example shows that we cannot conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ diverges knowing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$.

These two examples together show that no conclusion can be made about the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ based upon knowing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=1$.